# Trim whitespace at Vue template compilation

Tags: vue.js, prettier

I'd want to use Prettier to format the `<script>` part my Vue project, but I've encountered a slight hiccup.

Prettier will also format the `<template>` as it deems correct and I'm also statisfied with the results of this formatting.

The problem:
If I have any kind of list in the template Prettier will format it like this:

```
<ol class="faq-question">
  <li>
    My long answer
  </li>
  <li>
    My other long answer
  </li>
</ol>
```

Which I said I like, but what I don't like is that Vue will ALWAYS convert the whitespace between my `<li>` opening tag and 'My long answer' into exactly one space as [indicated in the documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-compileroptions-whitespace). But this causes all my list elements to start with a space which I dislike very much.
The result:

```
-  My multiple line
  answer looks weird
```

I tried to congiure Prettier to leave these kinds of cases alone, but couldn't find any global solutions. (I found that I can indicate it with a comment, but I can't leave a comment for every one of my `<li>` tags.)

#### My problem would be solved if either:

- I can congigure Vue to not add a space for the starting and ending of the element. (preferred)
- I can configure Prettier **globally** to leave these tags alone and not format them.

(I'm using Vue 2.7 in progress with migrating a medium sized project to Vue 3 if that matters)

- Tried configuring Vue's compiler options to leave the space form the beginning

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's the best solution but you can create your **own trim vue directive**:

```
<li>Test</li>
<li v-trim> Test</li>

import Vue from "vue";

Vue.directive("trim", {
  inserted: (el) =>
    (el.firstChild.textContent = el.firstChild.textContent.trim()),
});
```

Comment: Yes I considered that, and it'd be a good solution if I had only a handful of cases. Unfortunately I have hundreds of these, scattered across multiple files :( That is why I am explicitly looking for a global solution which doesn't need me to tend to each case line-by-line